# Lagrange Multiplier question: are points saddle, maximum, minimum?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Assume we have the right conditions of continuity and differentiability. Let's say I have $n$ constraints $g_i(x,y,z)=0$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. I form the Lagrangian and find the critical points.

**Question:**
Is there any easy way of checking whether these points are saddle, maximum or minimum?

Comment: There are second order KKT sufficient conditions, look, for example, [here, p. 51](https://www.math.uh.edu/~rohop/fall_06/Chapter2.pdf).

Comment: Not sure what yo mean with "easy", but, under certain conditions of regularity of the lagrangian function, there is a systematic method to find out what kind of extrema are found using [the bordered hessian](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~clark/285/2006-07/handouts/lagrange-2deriv.pdf).